# Make Niagara System effect visible only on specific Render Target

Tags: unreal, unreal-5, rendertargets, visibility-determination, multiple-render-targets

I’m new to UE and don’t really know how to approach my problem, perhaps that’s why I couldn’t google a solution for it. So here’s what I want to achieve:

I need a Niagara System effect to be only visible on the video camera. In other words, players cannot see the effect by looking at it directly, but if they use a video camera (in-game object) then the effect is visible on the camera display.

The video camera is implemented with a Material created from a Render Target put on the camera’s mesh. The camera can be picked up by the player and carried around, so the player can see the environment through it. I can think of two ways to solve my issue: either make NS effect invisible for eyes but somehow detectable by the camera or add the effect directly on the Render Target so I don’t have to deal with the effect’s invisibility. None of these ideas brings me anywhere.

I imagine I’m not the first to implement this, so there must be rather a straightforward solution. If somebody could describe how this can be done at least on a high level so I can figure out the details, it would be highly appreciated. If the trick is impossible with Niagara System, doing it with particles or even static meshes would be an option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a `sceneCapture2D` to capture the effect, and then set the value of `bVisibleInSceneCaptureOnly` to TRUE for my Niagara System:

[image: screenshot showing setting]

Comment: Thank you! I almost gave up on this but it turned out to be so easy. Exactly what I was looking for.